# Play a chunk of a video buffer

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, media-player

I have a byte stream in the memory that belongs to a video file.

Note that, the byte stream does not represent the whole video file, it is rather a chunk of the video file in bytes that I have available at that moment.

I want to be able to play this chunk on a video player, or stream it if you will. But, I want to control the flow of the stream by myself since I receive the source of the video from different servers.

I looked on the internet and I cannot find this particular information. It is generally handled by a player that doesn't let me control the stream or it asks for the whole file.

Remember that this is the topic of my thesis and I do not wish to use alternative available technologies which do everything automatically.

Comment: What format is the video file data? If its mjpeg, this should be easy. If its a more complex codec/format, it will be far more difficult.

Comment: I can choose MJPEG format file. What is the solution for that?

Comment: Mjpeg is basically a long sequence of jpeg frames in a single file or byte stream. Usually each jpeg has a header starting with "--videoboundary" or similar. All you need to do is find the jpeg starting tags and parse out the jpeg frames one at a time. Then display them as you would an image.

Comment: Exactly same scenario we need it. We tried with the below solution. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video#_articleTop But its load the full file. In our case chunk of data comes dynamically. So its not suitable.

Suggest any other suitable code to overcome this.

Thanks.